# Android SQLite rawQuery giving trouble

Tags: android, database, sqlite

There's this method which i've created to know if a contact exists in my Sqlite database.

```
public Cursor doesContactExist(String name) 
{
    return db.rawQuery("select * from contacts where name = ?; ", new String[] {name});
}
```

But whenever it is called from another activity it crashes only at this point....

```
if(db.doesContactExist(name)==null){   <== crashes here
                     try {                       
                        db.open();      
                        db.insertContact(name,cNumber);//name and number are Strings
                        listItems.add(name);           //a List View array
                        db.close();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //adapter for ListView

                            } 
                     catch (Exception e) {
                    //some code                                               }
                    }
```

According to me the rawQuery is having some troulble, especially the sql String in it.

Any help please?

Comment: please post the log cat.

Comment: don't use rawQuery. post stacktrace. open your database before querying it, not after (!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you try to make a select before your database is open:

```
if(db.doesContactExist(name)==null){   <== it is closed here
                 try {                       
                    db.open();      <== open the db here
```

change it to:

```
db.open();
if(db.doesContactExist(name)==null){
          try {
```

Comment: No i'm just a college grad. and am working on this college project.

Comment: Oh sorry i'm not that used to stackoverflow. Answer accepted ;) thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might help you..

```
db.open();
if(db.doesContactExist(name)==null)
{
     try
     {
          // Your Code Here..
     }
}
```

and in Database Class

```
public Cursor doesContactExist(String name) 
{
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE name=?", new String[ {name.toString()});
}
```

use db.open() method before using any database function because it will open your connection with database.. and at last don't forget to close database like db.close() and if you are using Cursor anywhere in code please close this also. it not generates any error but it gives you warnings. :)